# GremlinPipeline sorting without index edge label

Tags: titan

I have this code in java

```
GremlinPipeline gp = new GremlinPipeline();
gp.start(v).inE("hasLabel").outV().order(TransformPipe.Order.DECR).range(start, end);
```

I have not indexed edge label `hasLabel` in Titan even then its sorting in correct order.

- So how will i know its taking advantage of Vertex Centric Approach
  while using `GremlinPipeline` ?
- It doesn't care about Titan Indexing ?

In titan configuration file i specified `query.force-index=true`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Titan your are using but untill `0.5.0` using `GremlinPipeline` do not care about `query.force-index=true` this will work if you are using Titan api.